# Can I add the Facebook app itself as a 'valid native platform'?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm implementing device login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices

This works perfectly if the user visits https://facebook.com/device and remains in the browser. If the user goes through the Facebook app (Android in this case) they are given this error after entering the code:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.

My thinking here is that it is refusing because I'm accessing from a native app so would it be possible to register the Facebook app itself to the "Add platform" option in the dev portal?

If so I can get the Google Play Package Name and main activity but what about the key hashes??

Answer (score 0):

yes, I am using google sign in as my primary log in method in an app. This removes the hassle of creating an authentication system

Comment: Any idea how I can obtain the key hashes so?